# Getting Video View Count from Facebook APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to figure out which (if any) API will allow me to access Video View Count (views for a given facebook video).  I've looked through the documentation for Atlas, Graph, and Marketing API but I can't seem to find any API call that would return this metric.

Was this stripped from the APIs after the issues surrounding the authenticity of the metrics arose a few months back?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do an insights request for the post that includes the video. There are many metrics, all documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights#metrics).

You'll also need enough permissions to the page; you cannot look at someone else's posts' insights (therefore the example below will return empty data).

For example `127615610597242_1608135349211920/insights/post_video_views`

Example output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "post_video_views",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1111,
          "end_time": "2016-11-24T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 2222,
          "end_time": "2016-11-25T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 3333,
          "end_time": "2016-11-26T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Daily Total Video Views",
      "description": "Daily: Total number of times your video was viewed     for more than 3 seconds. (Total Count)",
      "id":     "127615610597242_1608135349211920/insights/post_video_views/day"
    },
    {
      "name": "post_video_views",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 44444
        }
      ],
      "title": "Lifetime Total Video Views",
      "description": "Lifetime: Total number of times your video was     viewed for more than 3 seconds. (Total Count)",
      "id":     "127615610597242_1608135349211920/insights/post_video_views/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```